# k-permutations in lexicographical order

Tags: python, iterator, combinatorics

I'm trying to generate k-permutations (variations) in lexicographical (alphabetical) order. For example, this code

```
import itertools

a = list('ABCD')
k = 2

for c in itertools.combinations(a, k):
    for p in itertools.permutations(c):
        print "".join(p),
```

prints

```
AB BA AC CA AD DA BC CB BD DB CD DC
```

and I'm looking for

```
AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
```

The answer needs to be iterable, so `sort` is not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use `permutations` without `combinations`:

```
import itertools

a = 'ABCD'
k = 2

for p in itertools.permutations(a, k):
    print "".join(p),
```

#### See also:

- [Documentation for `permutations(iterable[,r])`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> ["".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(a, k)]
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BA', 'BC', 'BD', 'CA', 'CB', 'CD', 'DA', 'DB', 'DC']
```